# Gradle and Artifactory Plugin with API Key

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am currently running into trouble with the Artifactory Plugin for Gradle.
We are working in corporate and have read access to some artifacts via api key (We do not have access to a `username:password` combination). Now I am struggling with including the key into our gradle build (configuring the Artifactory Plugin). Is there any solution to this or **is there any support** for api key authentication in the Artifactory Plugin?

Comment: Hi. See https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/GAP-242 : I don't think it's possible to use API key with current verson of the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I configured gradle to use my Artifcatory API key by adding this to my `gradle.properties` file:

```
# configure Artifactory access
artifactoryContextUrl=<url>
artifactoryUser=<username>
artifactoryPassword=<api-key>
```